# Couchbase CRUD API

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, couchbase

We're extending the .NET couchbase client to add some additional functionality (something analogous to transactions, or rather rollback) and one of the things on my radar is support for record locking.

I'm aware of check-and-set which would prevent updates without having the CAS value, but what I'm trying to do is prevent dirty reads by using the getlock functionality of couchbase (which is available on the Python client and therefore presumably the server, but not the .NET client)

My first thoughts were that it might be available by the REST API, but after doing some research it looks as though the API can only be used for querying views. I'm aware that memcached has a telnet interface but it's probably too much to hope that it's available there. If it were as simple as just making a call server-side I guess it would already be in the client...

Could use the [lease out](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-devguide-2.0/reserving-documents.html) model but would prefer not to go down that route if the functionality is there just tantalizingly out of reach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getl support is not currently implemented in the .NET client right now (2/20/13), but it is scheduled to be added soon (http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/NCBC-231). One thing to also note is that getl does not prevent other connections from reading, but only prevents other connections from writing to a locked key.

Also, I don't quite understand why you are trying to prevent dirty reads since Couchbase does not allow you to read from replica servers. In other words every read will always return the most recent value in Couchbase.

*Note Couchbase does have a replica read api, but by calling this you are explicitly saying your okay getting an old item.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the clarification

The kinds of use-case I'm trying to code for is this:

Reading document A which links to document B but document B hasn't been committed yet. I don't want the changes to document A to be visible until document B is also in a state that it could be read from. That's why I was looking for something like record locking.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand how you could get the dirty read. It sounds like what you really need is a transaction which is not supported by Couchbase or any of the other noSql databases as far as I know. I would recommend that you post your use case on the Couchbase forums since there are people there who can help you structure you data so that you wouldn't need to use transactions. In the worst case scenario you might get a dirty read, but since Couchbase is so fast the window for this happening would be extremely small.

Comment: Yeah agreed - transaction(ality) is what I'm trying to accomplish - thought that by record locking we may gather a measure of protection against situations like the above but even with locks you'd still need to unlock documents in parallel for it to be truly atomic... may not be a massive deal though due to the speed of CB as you said. Can also build some measure of protection against this in the app layer.

Comment: Transactions or something like it will likely be added to Couchbase in a future release.